# Woocommerce variations as a list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there away to list all variations of a product instead of using the dropdown.

each one showing its own image, name and qty, like the attache image.

[image]
thanks in advances

Comment: Show us what you've tried till now.

Comment: i've attached image, each variation like so

Comment: Hi. WooCommerce questions are off-topic on here. However you can ask your question in [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61002/woocommerce) room.

Comment: Hi Jack, i understand WooCommerce is only a plugin but its probably one of the most widely used and therefore will generate many questions.